# GPIO Pin Control SAMC21

Tags: c, boolean, atmel, cortex-m, sam

i'm having trouble trying to use my new SAMC21 Xplained Pro from Atmel. I'm currently trying to understand the basics of Cortex M0+, but i stuck. I'm using ASF in Atmel Studio. I started from basic, learning how to toggle the LED with the switch. This is Atmel's code, works flawless:

```
void configure_port_pins(void)
{
     struct port_config config_port_pin;
     port_get_config_defaults(&config_port_pin);
     config_port_pin.direction = PORT_PIN_DIR_INPUT;
     config_port_pin.input_pull = PORT_PIN_PULL_UP;
     port_pin_set_config(BUTTON_0_PIN, &config_port_pin);
     config_port_pin.direction = PORT_PIN_DIR_OUTPUT;
     port_pin_set_config(LED_0_PIN, &config_port_pin);
}
int main (void)
{
    system_init();
    configure_port_pins();
    while (true) {
       bool pin_state = port_pin_get_input_level(BUTTON_0_PIN);
       port_pin_set_output_level(LED_0_PIN, !pin_state);
    }
```

Then I wanted to try something simpler, like:

```
int main (void)
{
    system_init();
    configure_port_pins();
    port_pin_set_output_level(LED_0_PIN,0);

    while (1)
    {
        port_pin_set_output_level(LED_0_PIN,0);
        delay_ms(500);
        port_pin_set_output_level(LED_0_PIN,1);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. It's like it doesn't recognize bool data type. Maybe I'm missing something. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You think that code is not working because led is constantly on (or off, that depends on how hardware is connected)? It's because you don't sleep after second change, so output level 1 is set only for a brief moment (to be precise, time of `port_pin_set_output_level` execution), and your eye is not fast enough to see it.

Comment: Yes you are right but this doesn't work either:
while (1)
 {
  port_pin_set_output_level(LED_0_PIN,0);
  delay_ms(500);
  port_pin_set_output_level(LED_0_PIN,1);
  delay_ms(500);
 }